# keep groups of lines with specific keywords (bash)

Tags: linux, search, sed, grep

I have a text file with plenty of lines in this format (the lines between every two # defined as a group):

```
# some str for test
hdfv 12 9 b
cgj 5 11 t
# another string to examine
kinj 58 96 f
dfg 7 26 u
fds 9 76 j
---
key.txt:
string to
---
output:
# another string to examine
kinj 58 96 f
dfg 7 26 u
fds 9 76 j
```

I should search some keywords(string,to) from lines which starts with # and if the keywords does not exist in key.txt (a file with two columns) then I should remove that line and the following lines(of that group).I've written this code without result!(key words are together in input file as the example )

```
cat input.txt | while IFS=$'#' read -r -a myarray
do
a=${myarray[1]}
b=${myarray[0]}
unset IFS
read -r a x y z <<< "$a"
key=$(echo "$x $y")
if grep "$key" key.txt > /dev/null
then
echo $key exists
else
grep -v -e "$a" -e "$b" input.txt > $$ && mv $$ input.txt
fi
done
```

can some one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to get correct block is using `awk` and correct Record Selector:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} { RS="#";for (i in a)  if ($0~i) print}' key.txt input.txt
 another string to examine
kinj 58 96 f
dfg 7 26 u
fds 9 76 j
```

---

This should reinsert the `#` that is used and remove the extra empty line. I may be simpler ways to do this, but this works.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} { RS="#";for (i in a)  if ($0~i) {sub(/^ /,RS);sub(/\n$/,x);print}}' key.txt input.txt
#another string to examine
kinj 58 96 f
dfg 7 26 u
fds 9 76 j
```

Comment: Updated to us the data from `key.txt`

Comment: Added a second answer to fix missing `#` and remove extra empty line. Where is the deleted whitespace?